# How to change multiple attributes of a link using onclick of radio button?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to change multiple attributes of a link using the onclick attribute of a radio button. It isn't working though. I'm new to Javascript so any help would be much appreciated. This is my code so far.

```
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {"class": "first", "href": "http://www.google.com"});">First<br/>
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {"class": "second", "href": "http://www.stackoverflow.com"});">Second<br/>
<a id="submit" class="" href="">Click Here</a>

<script>
    function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
        for(var key in attrs) {
            el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your quotes are all messed up. You can't put double-quotes (eg `"class"`) inside your already double-quoted string (eg `onclick="..."`). Some reading for you ~ http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html

Comment: Thanks Phil. I did as you suggested. But the code still isn't working.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors.

Comment: I got this on the console..ReferenceError: setAttributes is not defined

Answer (score 2):

See this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/8f85m/)

```
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {'class': 'first', 'href': 'http://www.google.com'});">First<br/>
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {'class': 'second', 'href': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'});">Second<br/>
<a id="submit" class="" href="">Click Here</a>
```

The parameters you were passing had errors with `"` and `'` characters(quotes).

Comment: I changed the "s to 's where necessary but it still isn't working.

Comment: Please check the demo link. http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/8f85m/ .  Or post your edited code again.

Comment: @Bidhan A, Post the whole html markup including script tags for the function definition. Or a Jsfiddle link will also do.

Comment: See: 3 things- 
1. In jsfiddle, do not use head, body tags.
2. Add javascript code to the javascript section.
3. Choose an extension(jquery) if required, and `No wrap in <body>` in the next dropdown in case you use `onclick = 'someFunction()'`

Answer (score 0):

JS code would be

```
<script>
function setAttributes(el) {
    for(var key=1;k<arguments.length;k++) {
        el.setAttribute(arguments[k], arguments[k+1]);
        k++;
    }
}
</script>
```

and HTML would be

```
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), "class", "first", "href" "http://www.google.com");">First<br/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `"` with single `'` in your onclick= "  ... "

```
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {'class': 'first', 'href': 'http://www.google.com'});">First<br/>
<input type="radio" name="test" onclick="setAttributes(document.getElementById('submit'), {'class': 'second', 'href': 'http://www.stackoverflow.com'});">Second<br/>
<a id="submit" class="" href="">Click Here</a>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function setAttributes(el, attrs) {
        for(var key in attrs) {
            el.setAttribute(key, attrs[key]);
        }

    }
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4vu4a/1/)**

Comment: @BidhanA You check the demo link i provided

Comment: It still doesn't work. I get this error on console: ReferenceError setAttributes is not defined.

Comment: @BidhanA It's not `setAttributes` its `setAttribute`. I can see its workin in fiddle