# Other host and my client side function properly but my server side fails at onClick Javascript youtube player

Tags: javascript, html

Using the pure html source code from the website below for a responsive youtube player on server side, it runs identical to the hyperlink's host. When I upload this into file into my google cloud server, the onclick function fails to change the ID attribute. The scrolling and other java works fine. Competently identical code.

```
http://woosterwebdesign.com/experiments/youtube-player.html
```

1st fail:  link a script.js and structure the code differently

2rd fail:  Change the javascript formatting.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27140952/how-to-change-video-source-onclick

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23693118/how-to-change-multiple-attributes-of-a-link-using-onclick-of-radio-button

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41354535/how-to-update-youtube-video-id-when-clicking-different-play-buttons
```

3th fail: After reading many variations on stack and such, I found this demo below and uploaded the identical code and now see the same problem persist.

```
https://jsfiddle.net/u3bntba6/
```

At this point i'm certain it's somehow the google cloud. After apache2 trials and tribulation, I figured I didn't have something properly installed on Google Cloud Platform VM.

4th fail:  test and confirm that JQuery is installed and not the fault

Now I'm days deep in reading and I'm not sure what I'm looking for. I enjoy reading but can't find what I don't know. Any advice on how to get my server hosting a working youtube playlist would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can anyone host either example listed and confirm if the onclick feature works for them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After cycling my code into the server,
copying the code from the browser and re-pasting into my notepad, 
saving, 
and uploading again into the server.

I have noticed certain code is displayed with additional text that once ran again would cause functioning error. This can be easily mimiced by copying the element of an embedded youtube player and noticing additional code after the ? (meaning the break)

Same thing happened with my paypal button code. It must be an intentional layer of security. Except this time the code was rewritten in a way that could not be fixed without source. This is more likely js side I believe.

It is very likely if you're experiencing this in the future, you have broken code hiding in your html and javascript.